# Postgresql SELECT ORDER BY Column generated by WITH

Tags: postgresql

I have `SELECT` query on Postgre that contain `WITH` subquery as json column. I need to order query result based on `WITH` subquery json data or column.

This is a sample query that I ran:

```
SELECT 
    person.id,
    ( WITH person_warehouse AS (
             SELECT count(warehouse.id) AS total_warehouse,
                    sum((warehouse.detailinfo -> 'total_area'::text)::numeric) AS total_area_storage
             FROM warehouse
             WHERE warehouse.owner_id = person.id
             GROUP BY warehouse.owner_id
            )
     SELECT row_to_json(person_warehouse .*) AS json_tree
       FROM person_warehouse) AS warehousedata,
FROM 
  person
ORDER BY warehousedata->>'total_warehouse' DESC
```

But it is return that warehousedata is not a column. How can I sort select query based on subquery result?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can reference an alias in the `ORDER BY` clause, but you cannot use that alias in an expression. You'd have to repeat the expression from the `SELECT` list.

This query is written in a spectacularly complicated fashion, it could be written much simpler:

```
SELECT person.id,
       json_build_object(
          'total_warehouse',
          count(warehouse.id),
          'total_area_storage',
          sum((warehouse.detailinfo ->> 'total_area')::numeric)
       ) AS warehousedata
FROM person
   LEFT JOIN warehouse
      ON warehouse.owner_id = person.id
GROUP BY person_id
ORDER BY count(warehouse.id) DESC;
```

If you *really* want the `ORDER BY` clause sorted as a string, throw in a type cast.

Comment: I have fixed the answer, I made a bad mistake there.

Comment: Hmm, so basically WITH operation is cannot / not recommended to be used if we want to sort based on operation result. At the end, JOIN is the only way. Thank you on your insight for this problem.

Comment: `WITH` can be used just fine. As I said, the problem is that you cannot use an alias in an expression in `ORDER BY`. You'd have to use another layer of subquery to make your solution work, but why make it complicated if it can be simple?